# Unable to lookup service com.apple.CoreSimulator.host_support: 0x3

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode9.2, xcode9.4

I am using Xcode 9.2 and 9.4 and not able to run any application on simulator. It always gives me this error **Unable to lookup service com.apple.CoreSimulator.host_support: 0x3**. I have reinstall both xcode but still same problem. also installed command line tools but still same problem.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Updated XCode to 11.3 - didn't help
Run simulator and "Erased all content and settings ..." - worked for me.

Simulator started to fail after I cleared DerivedData folder contents.